# Show username in after login in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, identity

I'm new to ZF2, and I followed an authentication tutorial that I found here : https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/zend-framework-2-working-with-authenticationservice-and-db-session-save-handler/

After logging in, I followed his instruction (in the comment zone)  on how to use `$this->identity()`

```
//config/module.config.php ....
'service_manager' => array(
   'factories' => array(
      'AuthStorage' => 'SanAuthWithDbSaveHandler\Factory\Storage\AuthStorageFactory',
      'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => 'SanAuthWithDbSaveHandler\Factory\Storage\AuthenticationServiceFactory',
    ),
),
```

But it generates this error:

> "Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\InvalidServiceNameException' with message 'A service by the name or alias "Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService" already exists and cannot be overridden; please use an alternate name' in C:\xampp1\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php: "

Please can anyone Help me!

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is quite clear. It says that you are trying to register your service with the name `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` which already exists in ZF2. You have to alternate the name.

Make this changes in your `module.config.php`:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
       'AuthStorage' => 'SanAuthWithDbSaveHandler\Factory\Storage\AuthStorageFactory',
    ),
   'aliases' => array( // make sure "aliases" and not "alias"
       'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => 'my_auth_service',
    ),
   'invokables' => array(
       'my_auth_service' => 'SanAuthWithDbSaveHandler\Factory\Storage\AuthenticationServiceFactory',
    ),
),
```

Comment: I've tried it, still the same error. I don't know what i have done wrong. there must be something

Comment: No! can you lease tell me more details? do i rename it in the "module.config.php?"